# Merge Multiple Selects in one request

Tags: teradata

I have to extract a data using selects statements based on same conditions with a little change, I would like to make union for all my select in one statement:

```
select   Date_,  application_name,count(*)   total1  
from   PDETAIL
where Application_Name='My_Apllication' and  
SUBSTR(Statistics_Variables,36,1)='1'  and
File_Arriving_Date between date-29 and date-1
group by 1,2
```

and

```
select   Date_,  application_name,count(*)   total2  
from   PDETAIL
where Application_Name='My_Apllication' and  
SUBSTR(Statistics_Variables,38,1)='1'  and
File_Arriving_Date between date-29 and date-1
group by 1,2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT Date_,
       application_name,
       SUM(SUBSTR(Statistics_Variables,36,1)='1') total1,  
       SUM(SUBSTR(Statistics_Variables,38,1)='1') total2
FROM pdetail
WHERE Application_Name='My_Apllication' 
  AND File_Arriving_Date BETWEEN DATE-29 AND DATE-1
GROUP BY 1,2
```

If the query would produce 'Syntax error' (DBMS is NOT MySQL as the question is tagged) then

```
SELECT Date_,
       application_name,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(Statistics_Variables,36,1)='1' THEN 1 END) total1,  
       COUNT(CASE WHEN SUBSTR(Statistics_Variables,38,1)='1' THEN 1 END) total2
FROM pdetail
WHERE Application_Name='My_Apllication' 
  AND File_Arriving_Date BETWEEN DATE-29 AND DATE-1
GROUP BY 1,2
```